# Ansible: sudo confusion

Tags: ansible, sudo

New to Ansible.
I was testing a new a playbook and discovered an odd result.

I started with this simple YAML

```
- hosts: dpa18
  tasks:
    - name: Check sudo access via  sudo --list
      command: sudo --list
      register: sudo_access
...
```

The resulting output yielded:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************
ok: [dpa18]

TASK [Check sudo access via  sudo --list] *******************************************************
[WARNING]: Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo

changed: [dpa18]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************
dpa18      : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

I updated the YAML with a single line:

```
---
- hosts: dpa18
  tasks:
    - name: Check sudo access via  sudo --list
      become: yes
      command: sudo --list
      register: sudo_access
...
```

and re-ran it. (*wrapped for readability*)

```
PLAY [dpa18] ***********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dpa18]

TASK [Check sudo access via  sudo --list] ******************************************************************************************
fatal: [dpa18]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, 
        "module_stderr": "Warning: Permanently added 'dpa18,10.0.0.217' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n
                Authenticated to dpa18 ([10.0.0.217]:22).\r\n
                Connection to dpa18 closed.\r\n
                Transferred: sent 2908, received 2472 bytes, in 0.1 seconds\r\n
                Bytes per second: sent 30231.6, received 25699.0\r\n",
        "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n",
        "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
        "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
dpa18      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I am confused as to why "*a password is required*" to simply `--list` what commands are available to the user.  I believe that `sudo --list` is **not** really practical for Ansible, but curiosity has piqued my interest in the above output.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible, or the user in which you're authenticated with, is not authorized to perform sudo commands without a password. Therefor you need to specify this with the `-K` flag.

It's not about the command itself, but rather simply running any command with the `sudo` prefix.
On the host you're trying to perform the command, you could set this in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
<user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: That sudoers line seems like overkill, but I'll give `-K` a try and see how the results change.

Comment: `ansible-playbook -K` is useless in this case: 1) the root password is unknown and (2) the unprivileged user has no password on the remote server; only uses ssh keys to authenticate in.